# How to execute mozjpeg on image before serving on nginx?

Tags: nginx, mozjpeg

How to execute mozjpeg on image before serving on nginx?

I can't seem to find any documentation on nginx nor any tutorial online that does this. Hopefully someone can point me to a resource that helps.